# window.open is not working inside echo

Tags: javascript, php, edit

I'm trying to add  `onclick="window.open()"`  to `<? Echo "<a></a>" ?>`

My code:

```
<?php
echo "<a href='$path'
    onclick='window.open('" .$path. "',
                         'newwindow',
                         'width=300,height=250');
              return false;''
 >Pop</a>";
```

I have a problem with quotes outside `Echo` my code working pretty good but inside it doesn't work because of quotes changes.

Is there any solution for that?

Comment: Remove the `echo` and PHP tags and use HTML normally and when you want to output the variable, use `<?= $path ?>`. Your code will work and it'll look readable.

Comment: @Script47 it's just a sample of my code but thanks for ur comment i will do it next time ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

escape out quotes with `\"` so it ends like this:

```
<?php
echo "<a href=\"".$path."\" 
         onclick=\"window.open('" .$path. "', 'newwindow', 'width=300,height=250');return false;
     \">
         Pop
     </a>";
```

Comment: Sure, this'll work but it'll look terrible and it'll be hard to maintain.

Answer (score 2):

```
<a href='<?= $path ?>' onclick='window.open("<?= $path ?>", "newwindow", "width=300,height=250"); return false;'>Pop</a>
```

> echo also has a shortcut syntax, where you can immediately follow the opening tag with an equals sign. Prior to PHP 5.4.0, this short syntax only works with the short_open_tag configuration setting enabled.
>
> The major differences to print are that echo accepts an argument list and doesn't have a return value.

**Reading Material**

[`echo`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php)

Answer (score 0):

You already write two single quote after each other in :

```
... onclick='window.opened('  ....
```

and it will cause to string that echoed will be broken from the second qoute place,you can use \" when u want to wite quotes.do this instead :

> `<?php`
>   `echo "<a href='$path'`<
>   
>      onclick=\"window.open(' " .$path. " '.....
>   
>                     ....`'width=300,height=250')\";